# W3C validator: "Start tag a seen but an element of the same type was already open."

Tags: html, w3c-validation

I’m validating my first website on the W3C validator.

I get this error:

> Error: Start tag a seen but an element of the same type was already open.
>   From line 13, column 2; to line 13, column 35
>
> ```
> re.-->↩   ↩   <a href="index.html#introduction"><p>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I see that you have not closed the a tag here.
`<a href=""> is supposed to have </a>`

There must be a previous  tag which is not closed which is why you are getting this error.